# Recover data from incorrectly terminated bag

Tags: rosbag, bagfile, rosbag-record

I have bag whose recording was abruptly terminated due to a power outage. When I run `rosbag reindex` I can see that the reindexed bag is around 300 KB smaller than the unindexed bag. When I use the Python rosbag API directly to reindex, I hit the following section of the code:

```
# If the chunk header size is 0, then the chunk wasn't correctly terminated - we're done
if chunk_header.compressed_size == 0:
    raise ROSBagException('unterminated chunk at %d' % chunk_pos)
```

Do you know of any way that I can correctly terminate the chunk, so that I can recover that lost data, or is it not possible?